# Find limit of recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$0 \leq a\leq \frac{1}{4}$

$a_{1} = a,$     $a_{n+1} = a + (a_{n})^{2}$

I have to prove that the sequence has a limit, and to find the limit $a_{n}$.

Actually, I have no idea what to do.
I just know that the sequence is monotonic increasing, and I dont know why, i think that the lim is $a$. 
Thanks.

Comment: Just a small remark: If you think $a_{n+1} > a_n$, then the limit can never be $a_1=a$.

Comment: Here's something: let your recurrence be $f(a_n) = a_{n+1}$. If you already know the sequence has a limit, then that limit must be a fixed point of $f$. That is, if the limit is $x$, then we must have $f(x) = x$. (Take a minute to convince yourself that's true -- I find it pretty remarkable.)

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f(x)=a+x^2,\quad b=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4a}}{2}$$
Then
$$f(x)-x=\left(x-b\right)\left(x-(b+1)\right)$$
$$f(x)-b=\left(x-b\right)\left(x+b\right)$$
$$x\le f(x)\le b\quad\text{if }0\le x\le b\tag{1}$$
As $b\ge0$ for $0\le a\le\frac14$,
$$0\le a=\frac{1-(1-2b)^2}4=b-b^2\rightarrow a<b$$
Then, we can claim that for all $n\ge1$,

> $$a_n\le a_{n+1}\le b\tag{2}$$

that can be proven by induction:

First, it is obvious that $0\le a_n$ for all $n$.

As $a_1=a$ and $0\le a \le b$, using $(1)$
$$a_1\le a_2=f(a_1)\le b$$
it holds for $n=1$.
Now if $a_{n-1}\le a_n\le b$, then as $0\le a_n\le b$, using $(1)$
$$a_n\le a_{n+1}=f(a_n)\le b$$
So it holds for all $a_n$.

Now $(2)$ was proven so $a_n$ increases and bounded to $b$, and therefore $a_n$ converges.

And $a_n<b<1$, $a_n^2$ also converges.
Now we can do 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = L=a+\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^2=a+L^2$$
that gives us
$$L=b$$